# Angular com ngRouter não funciona quando digito no browse

Tags: angularjs, controller, ngroute, ng-controller

Preciso digitar no browse...

> dominio.com.br/detalhes/1234

...e preciso que o controlador pegue este numero 1234 e execute sua tarefa. Tentei de tudo sem sucesso. 
OBS: Se eu criar uma ancora dentro da pagina atrelando o href a rota (`<a href="#/detalhes/1234">Rodar Controller</a>`) e clicar neste link, ele funciona normalmente, mas preciso que isso funcione digitando no browse.
Segue minha definição de rota e controller:

```
angular.module('confirmar.routers', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

  $routeProvider
    .when('/detalhes/:id', {
      controller: 'DetalhesController'
    })

    .otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}])

.controller('DetalhesController',['$routeParams', function ($routeParams) {
  console.log('Detalhes exibido sobre o código: ' + $routeParams.id);
}]);
```

Preciso que funcione digitando no browse pois o cliente receberá um email com o link: `http://www.dominio.com.br/detalhes/<seu codigo>` e quando ele clica neste link, abrirá o browse exibindo os detalhes do item `<seu codigo>`

Comment: faltou vc informar o base

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

olha na sessão relative links, está escrito: 
Relative links
Be sure to check all relative links, images, scripts etc. Angular requires you to specify the url base in the head of your main html file (<base href="/my-base/index.html">) unless html5Mode.requireBase is set to false in the html5Mode definition object passed to $locationProvider.html5Mode(). With that, relative urls will always be resolved to this base url, even if the initial url of the document was different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se você não implementou redirecionamento no seu servidor em casos `404 NOT FOUND`, sua aplicação não irá funcionar.

Ao usar o modo HTML5 o navegador irá solicitar a URL completa ao servidor sempre que o usuário digitar diretamente o URL (ou clicar em um link que não pertença à aplicação), navegar para outro servidor ou atualizar a página via *refresh*. Uma vez que o seu aplicativo AngularJS provavelmente é um SPA, isso significa que o servidor retornará um erro 404, já que você não tentou carregar `index.html`.

Para corrigir isso, você deve configurar seu servidor para redirecionar todas as suas requisições que resultem em 404 para seu index.html, e em seguida lidar com estados inesperados em seu provedor de rota.

[Fonte.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13832529/how-to-config-routeprovider-and-locationprovider-in-angularjs#comment37816398_13833371)

Answer (score 0):

Eu estava com um problema com o ngRoute em uma aplicação web ASP.NET MVC, resolvi passando os parâmetros que eu precisava para a viewbag.

```
public ActionResult Detalhes(int id){
      ViewBag.ClienteId = id;
      return View();

}
```

e no html da página passo para o ng-init:

```
...<div ng-controller="mycontroller" ng-init="getDetalhes(@ViewBag.ClienteId)>
```

mas se caso sua aplicação não seja ASP.NET MVC, você pode tentar injetando o $location no controller:

```
$location.path('/myURL/').search({param: 'value'});
```

ou pelo $routeParams :

```
config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/myURL/:param1', {
            templateUrl: 'path/myPage.html',
            controller: newController
            });
    }]);
```

E depois no controller:

```
var param1= $routeParams.param1;
```